# merge values into one collection using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table only able to submit maximum two times on each qid.

first submit = 'submitted' on status column.

second submit = 'resubmitted' on status column.

```
id username qid amount    status 
1    john    2    150    submitted
2    john    2    120    resubmitted
3    david   2    100    submitted
4    david   2     80    resubmitted
```

I want to add the first amount on a collection like below so I can simply display both amounts on view.

```
    "id" => 1
    "username" => john
    "amount" => "120.00"
 **"first_amount" => "150.00"**
    "status" => "resubmitted"
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($xxx as $x)

{{$x->amount}}
{{$x->first_amount}}

@endforeach
```

Is this possible?

Comment: not a clear question, what are the results

Comment: The data of the table is inconsistent with the description. I see 4 entries for the same qid.

Comment: Can resubmitted values be more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load data once:

```
$collection = Model::get();
```

And then use the collection without executing any additional queries:

```
@foreach($collection->where('status', 'resubmitted') as $x)
    {{ $x->amount }}
    {{ $collection->where('status', 'submitted')->firstWhere('qid', $x->qid)->amount }}
@endforeach
```

Or you can rebuild the collection to add `first_amount` to it:

```
$collection = $a->where('status', 'resubmitted')->map(function($i) use($collection) {
    $i['first_amount'] = $collection->where('status', 'submitted')->firstWhere('qid', $i['qid'])->amount;
    return $i;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i get this error when i try your first code. Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstWhere(). I will try second one.

Comment: @wwwrrrxxx please try updated code and also please show how exactly do you load the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "first_amount" column to the table with a default value of 0. Then it will be populated in the collection when you retrieve it. You can set the value of the "first_amount" when you insert the "resubmitted" rows.

It will also save you having to modify the collection to add a value into it.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i will consider your one if others way do not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your query or transform the result (via collection).

One possible solution (via Collection) is:

```
$collection = (new Collection($data))->groupBy('username')->map(function($userItems, $username) {
  $firstAmount = $userItems->where('status', 'submitted')->first();

  return $userItems->map(function($data) use ($firstAmount) {
    return array_replace_recursive($data, ['first_amount' => $firstAmount['amount']]);
  });
})->flatten(1);
```

This will add the first amount to all results.

Another way is like Alexey posted. Basically you fetch the the "resubmitted" values and add the first_amount into it. But, this will be added only into "resubmitted" values (items with 'submitted' won't have the first_amount key).